# How to make HTML.ActionLink with route using angularjs directive

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I have HTML.ActionLink which works great without angularjs like below:`@Html.ActionLink(@itemlist.ATitle, @itemlist.ActionName, @itemlist.ControllerName, new { Area = @itemlist.AreaName }, @itemlist.AttributeName)`

But I included angularjs ng-repeat and getting data from $scope and trying to use the directive/interpolation with HTML.ActionLink. this is using controller, action, areas, display and attribute properties from the object, but when used with ng-repeat it does not make a routable link. I search google, got the below code, but its not fitting into my requirement. `<a href="@Url.Action("{{report.ATitle}}", "{{report.ActionName}}", "{{report.ControllerName}}")/ {{report.AreaName}}" target="_self">Index</a> and below one also <a data-ng-href="@Url.Action("Edit", "Home")/{{row.Id}}" target="_self">Edit  </a>`

Comment: Url.Action is C# code which gets executed in server and your angular array /variables is not available at that time!

Comment: create a service to get all those url's from your back end...or manually map them yourself

Comment: creating all from my back end means?. Can You tell me how do I create the URLs and use them in ng-repeat.

Comment: And moreover you see that I am using Areas as well in my actionlink... And the purpose of the URLs to route to specific pages when clicked.

Comment: Thanks for you help, I finally made it working.